# How to add time format to locale on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-i18n

I use Activeadmin gem and here is error when I try to access my site: `ActionView::Template::Error (translation missing: ru.time.formats.long)`. It was same error in development mode on my local computer, and I just add

```
time:
  formats:
    long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

to activeadmin original ru locale in external libraries. No good, I know. But in production I can't do this. I tried to add this format to `config/locales` in my app, but nothing happen. How to add it?

**UPDATE** I'm sorry for my stupid question but will leave it here. Problem is solved by adding format to your locale in `config/locales` and **server restart**

Comment: Hey, glad you found a solution. However, it would be best if you post it as an answer. It's ok to answer your own question! And it is good to do so because people will know that no further attention is needed when browsing the list of questions. HF!

Comment: @Raffael, Thanks. Will do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved by adding format to your locale in `config/locales`

```
time:
  formats:
    long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

and **server restart**